# Is function invocation at translation time valid?

Tags: c, c99

I'm trying to achive a function to be called only one time. But I want to save the `if (firstTime)` check.
What I'm thinking about was:

```
while (1)
{
    foo();
}

foo()
{
    static int test = 1, srand (test);
    test++;
}
```

But I couldn't find anything in the standard what is covering this.
So I'm not sure about, this is undefined. And if not so, will srand be invoked as expected? If not so, is it (as the main question is) even possible to invoke functioncalls on translationtime (what would more be, behave as if), as I'm doing here?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `if( firsttime )`? Don't you think it's the most intuitive way to achieve what you want and the easiest to understand for others who might read your source later?

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt: Well ofc it is the most intuitive way. But if what I try in my snippet would work, that would result in better performance.

Comment: `static int test = 1, srand (test);` is not valid C.

Comment: @ouah: I suggested so allready, thats why I looked it up in standard. But as I found nothing about, ouah: Can you explain why it isn't?

Comment: Your are mixing a declaration and a statement with a `,` it's not valid.

Comment: @ouah So `int bar = foo2();` where `int foo2();` is the prototype, would also be invalid?

Comment: As an option to a first time flag, you could use a pointer to function that is initially set to the first time function, which in turn would set the pointer to function to the actual function. There's a level of indirection, but it eliminates a conditional branch.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Well, But that is what I do.

Comment: @Zaibis valid, you are not mixing a declaration and a statement in `int bar = foo2();`. It's a declaration.

Comment: @rcgldr Ouh, yeah thats great!

Comment: @ouah So would there be any work around doing something like `static void bar = srand(1)` as i don't care about `bar` i just want to abuse the static rules regarding to translation time.

Comment: @Zaibis - a more general version of this idea is to use the pointer to function as a "state machine", where each function "advances" (sets) the pointer to the next state (the next function as part of a series of functions). This can be handy for event or interrupt driven code.

Comment: @zaibis 1. you cannot declare an object of type void. 2. you cannot initialize a static qualified object with a value that is not a constant expression.

Comment: @ouah Well, nvm. I guess you don't get me.

Comment: To answer where the standard disallows it: This is a declaration of `test` and a declaration of a function, according to the grammar (see 6.7 and 6.7.6). Either `test` is a typedef (what it isn't here) or this is an _identifier-list_ violating 6.7.6.3 p3 "An identifier list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function
shall be empty."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is probably that using a function call as an initializer for a static variable would call that function only once a program startup.

No, this is not possible in C, only constants are allowed in that context. In C++ this would be possible, and the compiler applies some secret wisdom to know in which order such initializations are effected.

Answer (score 3):

As an option to a first time flag, you could use a pointer to function that is initially set to the first time function, which in turn would set the pointer to function to the actual function. There's a level of indirection, but it eliminates a conditional branch.

A more general version of this idea is to use the pointer to function as a "state machine", where each function "advances" (sets) the pointer to the next state (the next function as part of a series of functions). This can be handy for event or interrupt driven code. I've used this method for device drivers and embedded code.

Comment: Would love to acept this one, but my OP was about "is it valid what I do?" instead of "Could anyone find a solution for me". Sorry for that.

Comment: @Zaibis - which is why it starts off with "as an option" ...  It's an alternative approach that may solve the issue you're dealing with.